# Terraform - Interpolating variable values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to call a variable within the below, but having to enter it in manually at the moment, a little stuck. How do I get Terraform to automatically insert the variable's value.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "aws-admin-role" {
  name        = "AWS-AdminAccess"
  description = "Administration of Account from AWSxx"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{  
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[  
    {  
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":{  
        "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::INSERTACCOUNTMANUALLY:root"
      },
      "Action":"sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition":{  

      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: INSERTACCOUNTMANUALLY used to be where i was placing a variable, but with that in and populated in the variables file I am just getting whitespace so arn:aws:iam:::root

Answer (score 1):

Terraform allows you to interpolate values that it knows about such as variables or outputs from data sources, resources or modules.

In your case you could use the [`aws_caller_identity` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/caller_identity.html) to dynamically fetch the account ID of the caller and insert that into your IAM policy with something like this:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

resource "aws_iam_role" "aws-admin-role" {
  name        = "AWS-AdminAccess"
  description = "Administration of Account from AWSxx"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{  
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[  
    {  
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":{  
        "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:root"
      },
      "Action":"sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition":{  

      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

If, instead, you wanted to use a variable to refer to a different AWS account you could do something like this:

```
variable "account_id" {}

resource "aws_iam_role" "aws-admin-role" {
  name        = "AWS-AdminAccess"
  description = "Administration of Account from AWSxx"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{  
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[  
    {  
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":{  
        "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:root"
      },
      "Action":"sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition":{  

      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into the first option. Not sure if that would work, as I am entering in another account from where this is running. But if that goes live then that may well work using that method.

Comment: I did also try using this "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_admin_account}:root" so similar to your second options, this was what seemed to be ignored, even though it is in my variables file